# How do I get "git log --full-history [file]" in jgit

Tags: jgit, git-log

Specifically, I want to get a log that includes all merges that affect a file - it seems that for my repo, at the commandline, `git log [file]` doesn't show the merge, but `git log --full-history [file]` does.

(I can also see it in `git log -m --follow [file]` but not if I just specify `-m` or `--follow` alone, bizarrely. Something to do with merging a revert? I'm not sure.  The sequence of commits is:

- The file was changed on a branch, by reverting an old commit
- A PR was raised on github.com and merged

The file change shows up in all the logs - the merge doesn't)

JGit `LogCommand` with a `addPath` filter seems to mimic what git does - it shows me the commits on the file, but not the merge.

Comment: As far as I see, JGit currently does not support this in the LogCommand class. You would need to implement this yourself with the more low-level API (you probably can use LogCommand as starting point).